# System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from type 'Match' to type 'String' is not valid.'

Tags: vb.net

I searched stack overflow for this error, I found similar questions but the answers to those questions didn't fix my error/problem and it wasn't my exact error/problem.

So basically I have a listbox called "workingText" in VB.NET and I have a SaveDialog1 in the solution.  I have a save function to save the text from listbox to a text file.

Heres my code:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim banana As String = ""
        For Each apple As String In ListBox1.Items //this is where the error occurs.
            banana += apple & Environment.NewLine
        Next

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, banana)
    End If
End Sub
```

-I have a SaveFileDialog in the code/form, got it from toolbox.

Someone please help me with this!

Thanks!

Edit: Im a bit of a noob at vb.net, im more experienced (pro level) at c# and decent leveled of c++.

If someone could explain in noobie terms of how I could fix this that would be great :)

Error message:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' : 'The CLR has
>   been unable to transition from COM context 0xdc62f0 to COM context
>   0xdc6238 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination
>   context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or
>   processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows
>   messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact
>   and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory
>   usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all
>   single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait
>   primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump
>   messages during long running operations.'

Comment: You are treating the items in the `ListBox` as though they are `String` objects but, according to the error message, they are actually `Match` objects.  How exactly did you populate the control in the first place?  If you want `Strings` then you should populate it with `Strings`.  My guess is that you used a `Regex` and got `Match` objects that way.  If so, then you should get the actual `String` from the `Value` property of each `Match`.

Comment: Note that you could get the `String` from the `Value` property in this code, i.e. declare `apple` as type `Match` and then use `apple.Value`.  I would suggest that, unless you have a specific reason for loading `Match` objects into the `ListBox` though, it would be more appropriate to get the `Strings` out first.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks! It worked, but theirs one problem, it doesn't have a new line, so all the text is all squished together. How would I fix this?

Comment: Nevermind, just had to add & Environment.NewLine to it. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You might also consider writing out the lot in one line: `File.WriteAllLines(SaveFileDialog1.FileName, ListBox1.Items.Cast(Of String)())`

Comment: @jmcilhinney after fixing this and trying to save the text from ListBox1, it freezes for around 2 minutes and throws an expectation:

Comment: Heres the error: https://pastebin.com/raw/5C2RQRg0 How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't post links in comments when you can post (preferably) text directly in your question.  Screenshots should be an adjunct to information, not an alternative.

Comment: Sorry but it goes over 500 characters so I couldn't post it here.

Comment: I just edited the question and added the error message there, which is what you should have done.